# FlywayException: Unsupported Database: MariaDB 10.4

Tags: flyway

Error when trying to migrate with Flyway. 
Versions:

1. **Flyway: 7.8.2**
2. HikariCP: 4.0.3
3. mariadb-java-client: 2.7.2 (I also tried it with version 3.0.0-alpha)

```
[21:01:49 INFO]: [org.flywaydb.core.internal.license.VersionPrinter] Flyway Community Edition 7.8.2 by Redgate
[21:01:49 INFO]: [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource] SamplePool - Starting...
[21:01:49 INFO]: [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource] SamplePool - Start completed.
[21:01:49 ERROR]: [ExamplePlugin] Jdbc url: jdbc:mariadb://127.0.0.1:3306/app?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8&useSSL=false
[21:01:49 ERROR]: [ExamplePlugin] Migration error: 
org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unsupported Database: MariaDB 10.4
                at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.DatabaseTypeRegister.getDatabaseTypeForConnection(DatabaseTypeRegister.java:143) ~[?:?]
                at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcConnectionFactory.<init>(JdbcConnectionFactory.java:69) ~[?:?]
                at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:505) ~[?:?]
                at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:165) ~[?:?]
                at ru.example.clans.service.simple.SqlMigrateService.migrate(SqlMigrateService.java:30) ~[?:?]
                at ru.example.clans.ExamplePlugin.onPluginEnable(ExamplePlugin.java:95) ~[?:?]
                at ru.coder.api.BenioPlugin.onEnable(BenioPlugin.java:51) ~[?:?]
                at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:263) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-638]
                at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:380) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-638]
                at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:483) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-638]
                at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:501) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-638]
                at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:415) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-638]
                at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.loadWorld(MinecraftServer.java:591) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-638]
                at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:281) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-638]
                at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:1065) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-638]
                at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.lambda$a$0(MinecraftServer.java:289) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-638]
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) [?:?]
```

Comment: For anyone else affected: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/3168